Checking invertibility of a matrix or arbitrary size and known structure
I want to prove that the square symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with entries
$$ A_{ij} = \frac{1-(-1)^{i+j+1}}{(i+j+1)2^{i+j+1}} $$
is invertible for all sizes $n$. For better understanding, this is how it looks numerically:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{1}{1\cdot 2^0} & 0 & \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^2} & 0 & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & \ldots\\
         0 & \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^2} & 0 & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & 0 & \ldots\\
          \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^2} & 0 & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & 0 & \frac{1}{7\cdot 2^6} &\ldots\\
           0 & \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & 0 & \frac{1}{7\cdot 2^6} & 0 & \ldots\\
             \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^4} & 0 & \frac{1}{7\cdot 2^6} & 0& \frac{1}{9\cdot 2^8} & \ldots\\
          \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Any guesses about how to prove invertibility?
Many thanks!

Matrices of this form (where $A_{i, j}$ is a function of $i + j$) are called Hankel matrices. They occur as Gram matrices attached to inner products on spaces of polynomials; famously the Hilbert matrices arise in this way. Your example is a variation of the Hilbert matrix, and some messing around produces
$$A_{i, j} = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} x^i x^j \, dx = \langle x^i, x^j \rangle$$
where $\langle -, - \rangle$ is the $L^2$ inner product on $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.
In general, suppose $v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots \in V$ is a countable sequence of vectors in an inner product space $V$.

Theorem: The following conditions are equivalent:

The vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent.
The Gram matrices $A_n$ with entries $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle, 0 \le i, j \le n-1$, are all invertible.
The determinants $\det A_n$ are all positive.


So your desired invertibility follows from the fact that the monomials $x^i$ are linearly independent (together with the fact that the $L^2$ inner product above is positive-definite). In fact it's not hard from here to write down a closed form for the Hankel determinants, it will be some variation of the determinants of the Hilbert matrices.
